# How can I filter out URIs that match a scheme?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

This is a ActiveJob for a Ruby on Rails application/

I am using Anemone web crawler and have created and array of all the URIs on the home page of `www.example.com`. I want to filter out ones that do not have a certain path.

So `www.example.com/somepath` should be picked out and saved while `www.example.com/someotherpath` should not be picked out and saved.

The problem is that I cannot not filter these array entries. There is not a regexp method that I can use on them.

I require 'uri' at the top, but still receive `method does not exist` errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array's `select` and String's `include` to do the hard work.

```
your_array = [ URI('www.example.com/somepath'),
               URI('www.example.com/someotherpath') ]
filter = 'somepath'

your_array.select { |t| t.to_s.include?(filter) }

=> [URI("www.example.com/somepath")]
```

Comment: I will give this a try, but I do not believe that the URIs are strings, they are URI objects. String method do not work on them.

Comment: I'll update the code, though it seems URI can avail itself of a `.to_s`, which would not harm Strings in any case.

Comment: I was thinking of using that but Anemone has a .to_s method for CookieStore objects so I wasn't sure if it would perform correctly.

Comment: Happily, it does. :)

Comment: I was unable to get this to work, so I looked at the select method in the docs and figured to use the `.select!` method instead. It edits the array it's called on while `.select` yields a new array.

Comment: Ah! You needed to do the filter in-place. Completely understandable. So, yes, `.select!` rather than `.select`.

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will work for you.

```
http:\/\/example\.com\/somepath($|\/.*)
```

Write a ruby code that will check if string match this regex or not, and you are done.

Some thing like:

```
def right_string(string)
  string.match(http:\/\/example\.com\/somepath($|\/.*)) ## this return true / false
end
```